# Where to find DNA structural atomic coordinates?

Tags: computational-chemistry, structural-biology

I need a code/app/website that can receive a DNA sequence, for instance AATCT, and output a file with the atomic coordinates.

I used to do this on this [website](http://www.scfbio-iitd.res.in/software/drugdesign/bdna.jsp#1) but the service is no longer working and I haven't mange to find a substitute.

I found a [code](https://casegroup.rutgers.edu/fd_helix.c) that does this but doesn't include de H atoms .

I have also visited some data banks but they don't have what I'm looking for, I want to have control over the DNA sequence I want.

Comment: https://github.com/haddocking/3D-DART Maybe

Comment: [This compiliation](http://www.vls3d.com/index.php/links/bioinformatics/3d-structure-prediction/protein-dna-rna-glycan-modeling) mentions, e.g., the [hnadock server](http://huanglab.phys.hust.edu.cn/hnadock/) which eventually delivers computed (i.e., guessed) geometries as `.pdb`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the program AMBER, There is an option where you write an input with the sequence that you want, automatically the program will build the two strands, and your output will be pdb format. Or You can use Avogadro program direct and you will write the sequence and the output will be XYZ format.

[image]

The output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For batch use, I recommend [Open Babel](https://openbabel.org) which can translate `fasta` format DNA sequences into single or double-stranded DNA coordinates. (Indeed, it's used in Avogadro.)

[FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format):

```
> DNA
AATCT
```

Then you can use something like this ([documentation](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/FASTA_format.html?highlight=fasta))

```
obabel file.fasta -O file.pdb # output double-stranded
obabel file.fasta -O file.pdb -a1 # output single-stranded
```

And of course `file.pdb` could be `file.sdf` or `file.mol2` for other formats supported by Open Babel.